# MySql on Nodejs: Using connection from pool and running query does not release connection

Tags: mysql, node.js

Server is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Node.js is at 8.x LTS

Here is the script:

```
mysql = require('mysql'),

connOptions          = {};
connOptions.database = 'someDb';
connOptions.password = 'somePassword';
connOptions.host     = 'localhost';
connOptions.user     = 'someUser';
connOptions.connectionLimit =  10;

var dbConn = mysql.createPool(connOptions);
dbConn.query ("select 1", function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      throw err;
    }
    //dbConn.end();

});

console.log("At end and hanging!");
```

According to the documentation, this should release the connection. It does not. The program does not throw errors or console logs any. It simply hangs after displaying "At end and hanging." If I uncomment dbConn.end(), it ends.

**EDIT: OOPS! Read the documentation carefully. The pool must be closed explicitly after use with pool.end(). So the behavior is correct. I am not deleting the query as someone else may encounter a similar situation.**

Comment: It's okay you can post answer to your own question.